# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule() on RSS feed causes redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress installed on the domain `example.com`. I would like `example.com/feed.xml` and `example.com/feed/` to load the same page (the RSS2 feed). My permalinks are configured for pretty URLs (with the pattern `%postname%`).

`example.com/feed/` works, so I set out to create a rewrite rule for `feed.xml`. In `functions.php`, I put this:

```
function add_feed_xml_route() {
  add_rewrite_rule('feed.xml', 'index.php?feed=rss2', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'add_feed_xml_route');
```

I flushed the routes, but when I go to `example.com/feed.xml`, it redirects to `/feed.xml/feed/` before displaying the feed. Why is it redirecting? How do I stop it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it through functions.php I would do this through your .htaccess file.  It would look something like this:

`redirect 301 /feed.xml http://example.com/feed/`

If you want a basic tutorial on redirects check out http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: That was my first inclination, too. It works if I do a _redirect_ from `example.com/feed.xml` to `example.com/feed/`, but remember I want these two URLs to display the same content without a redirect. Theoretically, this is what the [passthrough flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) is for, but that didn't work, presumably because of a conflict with Wordpress's own .htaccess routing.

Comment: I guess I would ask why you want both of them to point to the same content instead of using a redirect.  I'm not sure how search engines handle feeds specifically, but typically having two links with the same content isn't great for search.

Comment: It's a really long story, but basically the Wordpress installation isn't publicly accessible. It's being used to generate a static site which gets scraped with wget.